# React router v.4 not render nested Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

My router Config:

```
export default [
  {
    exact:true,
    path: '/',
    component: Dashboard, // Add your route here

  },


  {

    path: '/backupjobs',
    component: Backup, // Add your route here
    routes: [
      { 

        path: '/backupjobs/jobdetail',
        component: Alert
      }
    ]
  },
```

I try render **component Alert** Like subroute. but it always show **Component Backup**

Link that I use :

```
<Link className="link-table" to={`${this.props.match.url}/jobdetail`}>Alert</Link>
```

How my router look likes:

```
routeWithSubRoutes(route) {
  return (
    <Route
      key={_.uniqueId()}
      exact={route.exact || false}
      path={route.path}
      render={props => (
        // Pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
        <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes || null} />
      )}
    />
  );
 } 

<Switch>
      {routes.map(route => this.routeWithSubRoutes(route))}
      </Switch>
```

URL address is changed in browser, but Always show **Backup Component**